# HiddenFor to display encoded character

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I have a string of items between passed to a hidden field for some jquery to use.  Some of items in the string have an apostrophe `'` in it, which the html helper is converting to `&#39;`

I've tried a few variations, but none seem to work:

- `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.qNotes)`
  normal
- `@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.HiddenFor(model => model.qNotes))`
  Displays it on page instead of hidden
- `@Html.Hidden(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.qNotes).ToString())`
  Still encodes it

Not sure how to proceed to pass this string as needed to my front end dev.

Comment: that is perfectly valid. is that causing another more specific problem?

Comment: I need it to NOT encode the character.

Comment: can you elaborate on why?

Comment: The string will be inserted into a text field when the user selects it from a list that is generated from this hidden field. So, if an option in the list is "Customer's Primary Id"  we need it to appear as an apostrophe and not encoded.

Comment: share that code. mvc is doing a very appropriate thing here - it sounds like your other code is causing the problem.

Comment: I've stepped through the backend, it's sending "Customer's Primary Id" to the model. When the HiddenFor puts it in the hidden field on the view, it's making it "Customer&#39;s Primary Id". I understand Encoding it is the appropriate thing to do in most circumstances, but is there not a @Html.Raw form of the HiddenFor field?

Comment: i mean your front end share your front end code. thats where the real problem is.

Comment: So I can't put it in the hidden field as "Customer's", I should tell my front end guy to deal with "Customer&#39;s"?

Comment: i would tell him not to care better to be flexible in both ways.

Comment: but it gets displayed to the end-user when they click on a certain area. It's not something that is simply always hidden from the user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59381/discussion-between-daniel-a-white-and-dave-k).